# Disponibilizar pasta SDK do Android para todos os usuários

Tags: android

Trabalho com administração de laboratórios de informática em uma universidade. Passo por uma situação com o Android Studio, onde em um usuário baixo todas as dependências do SDK, só que ao logar com outro usuário é necessário fazer o download novamente.

Existe alguma maneira de deixar uma pasta padrão para todos os usuários por padrão no setup de inicialização de todos os usuário e evitando que precise realizar o download do SDK novamente?

Comment: É só deixar a pasta de instalação do SDK como pública para todos os usuários. É importante que tenha permissão de leitura e escrita, pra que qualquer um possa instalar atualizações. A forma de fazer isso vai variar de sistema pra sistema.

Comment: Pablo, obrigado pela resposta.
Esse procedimento eu já realizo por aqui, mas gostaria de uma forma de automatizar esse procedimento, pois são vários professores e palestrantes que dão aulas e oficinas de Android.

Queria alguma solução onde cada usuário que iniciasse o primeiro setup já por padrão identificasse onde está o SDK. Algo como uma variável padrão.

Comment: Automatizar que processo? Não está muito claro que falta ser feito, então.